# Is this possible w/ SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm working with a SQL database for a Skills Matrix application and I need a query to return a list of employees that are qualified for a given position.  Here's a brief overview of the relevant relationships:

- Employee has many skills through
  qualifications
- Position has many
  skills through requirements

Is there a efficient way to return a list of employees that have the qualifications to meet a certain position's requirements?

**EDIT**

```
employees
- id
- name

positions
- id
- title

skills
- id
- name

requirements
- position_id
- skill_id

qualifications
- employee_id
- skill_id
```

Comment: I sort of get what you're saying, but can you post something more concrete, maybe some table diagrams? Or is designing the tables part of the question?

Comment: Since, you tagged your post with both mysql and sql-server, can you clarify are you using mysql, ms sql server or both? Also it might help if you represent your overview of the relevant relationships in terms of tables and columns. Otherwise there is no point talking about efficiency as it depends on particular schema.

Comment: Aight I just added some diagrams, hopefully those help.  Will probably be SQL Server only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM requirements r
    WHERE r.position_id = 1234
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM qualifications q
        WHERE q.skill_id = r.skill_id
        AND q.employee_id = e.employee_id
    )
)
```

It will find all employees such that there are no requirement that is not filled by the employee's qualifications.

The use of nested `NOT EXISTS` is even mentioned in the [MySQL Reference Maual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's possible.  I count seven tables there:  Employee, Qualifation, EmployeeQualifications, Position, Requirement, PositionRequirements, and RequirementQualifications.  If your Qualifications and Requirements will ***always*** be 1:1 (ie, they are the same thing), you can do it more simply (5 tables) like this:  Employee, Position, Skill, EmployeeSkills, PositionSkills.

Once you have the tables defined, the trick to building the query is to first look for any positions for which an employee is *not* qualified, and then do an exclusion join with that result set back to the position table to get your results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to achieve what you want you need, given a Position to return only those Employees, that have qualifications that collectively include all the skills the Position requires. If you retrieve these Employees, this list it will represent the list of the customers you are after.

**Update**
Since I do not have any experience with mysql, my reply only deals with sql server. 
Try something like this:

```
select 
    qualifications.employee_id 
from 
    qualifications
join 
    requirements 
on 
    requirements.skill_id = qualifications.skill_id
where 
    requirements.position_id = 1234
group by 
    qualifications.employee_id
having
    count(qualifications.skill_id) = (select count(distinct skill_id) from requirements where requirements.position_id = 1234)
```

Create an index on each of

- employees.id
- qualifications.employee_id
- qualifications.skill_id
- requirements.skill_id
- requirements.position_id

Comment: Don't know about sql server, but MySQL will only use one index per table per query. You can put multiple columns in an index, but to be most effective the order of columns in the index should match the order of columns in the query-- so an index on (employee.id, name) would actually be faster than an index on (name, id).

Comment: @Dire: thank you for you comment, I haven't work with mysql, so I updated my answer, that it only reflects my knowledge of sql server.

Comment: this looks like it might find employees who meet _some_ of the requirements, not employees who meet _all_ of the requirements.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: you are of course right, thank you for this. Just not to repeat your answer, I'm giving implementation based on the number of distinct skills in the requirements. Do you see any problems with this?